# Unable to import data from MySql using Sqoop with different delimiter

Tags: hadoop, sqoop

As a beginner in Hadoop field, i was trying my hands on Sqoop tool (**Version** : Sqoop 1.4.6-cdh5.8.0).

Though i referred to various sites and forums but i could not get workable solution where in i could import data using any other delimiter other than `,`.

**PFB the code that i have used** :

--- Connecting to MySql, creating table and records with `,` in string.

```
mysql> create database GRHadoop;
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> use GRHadoop;
Database changed
mysql> Create table sitecustomer(Customerid int(10), Customername varchar(100),Productid int(4),Salary int(20));
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.22 sec)

mysql> Insert into sitecustomer values(1,'Sohail',100,50000),(2,'Reshma',200,80000),(3,'Tom',200,60000);
Query OK, 3 rows affected (0.06 sec)
Records: 3  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

mysql> Insert into sitecustomer values(4,'Su,kama',300,50000),(5,'Ram,bha',100,80000),(6,'Suz',200,60000);
Query OK, 3 rows affected (0.03 sec)
Records: 3  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0
```

**Sqoop Command :**

```
sqoop import \
--connect jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/GRHadoop \
--username root \
--password cloudera \
--table sitecustomer \
--input-fields-terminated-by '|' \
--lines-terminated-by "\n" \
--target-dir /user/cloudera/GR/Sqoop/sitecustomer_data \
--m 1;
```

**Expected Output :**

```
1|Sohail|100|50000

2|Reshma|200|80000

3|Tom|200|60000

4|Su,kama|300|50000

5|Ram,bha|100|80000

6|Suz|200|60000
```

**Actual output :**

```
1,Sohail,100,50000

2,Reshma,200,80000

3,Tom,200,60000

4,Su,kama,300,50000

5,Ram,bha,100,80000

6,Suz,200,60000
```

Please guide where i am getting it wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `--input-fields-terminated-by` argument is to tell Sqoop how to parse the input files during `export`. You should be using `--fields-terminated-by`, this argument controls how the output is formatted.

```
sqoop import \ 
      --connect jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/GRHadoop \ 
      --username root \ 
      --password cloudera \ 
      --table sitecustomer \ 
      --fields-terminated-by '|' \ 
      --lines-terminated-by "\n" \ 
      --target-dir /user/cloudera/GR/Sqoop/sitecustomer_data \ 
      --m 1;
```